Lost NETWORK list in file manager
File manager Browse Network shows blank this morning.  Yesterday I could see the Buffalo NAS.
I can get to the NAS via it's IP address in my internet browser (FireFox) but can't see it to connect in File Manager.
I suspect some update this morning has caused the problem.  Not sure where to start to fix this.  Windows box can see the NAS just fine.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Buffalo NAS  TS3410DBC6 (TS3410D)
LAN Port 1 192.168.12.10
Both SMB and AFP are allowed.
Why can't File Manager see anything with Browse Network?

Are both your computer and your NAS running Ubuntu. Could you add a screenshot of your Files app using the "picture" icon above the edit question window?

Only the laptop.  NAS is a Buffalo device.  I may be hosed.  This morning unable to boot.  The Ubuntu screen shows but no user name/password fields.  How does one do a clean install of Ubuntu without losing the User directory?  And with no login?

You can try booting from a Ubuntu live Installation USB using the Try Ubuntu option. Once booted, copy your users' home folder into a second (possibly larger) USB drive. After a clean install, copy your files from the big USB drive into your home folder. You may want to format the Big USB partition as ext4 so that copied files can retain all the file ownership and permissions information. Alternately, if you have regular backups saved in the NAS, you can restore your files from there after a fresh install.

I now have a fresh 24.04.1 LTS Ubuntu box.  Still cannot see the Buffalo NAS which should be called TS3410DBC6.

Screenshot added showing both the File Manager display and the Firefox Browser showing the admin screen for the Buffalo NAS

I can't see any edits to the question and no screenshots.

Not sure what happened to the .png file.
This is what I have learned:

Ubuntu 24.04.1 has removed Windows Network from File Manager as the underlying Samba protocol is not "secure".
By entering "smb://192.168.112.10/share" into the top bar File Manager was able to open the location and present the folders/files found there.
I had to do the same for the Backup utility for it to see the backup location.
Main take away -- Ubuntu removed Windows Network from File Manager in 24.04.1

